# My Ex-Boss is using my Accounting Software

Tags: management, applications, legal, software, harassment

I work as an accountant so I have my own QB Software, this allows me to install it on a PC. 
I was working for a company and installed the software.
 When I left I began the uninstall process and he stopped it.

Now he's using my license software.

**Can I sue him for that?**

Comment: Seems like a legal question and not a workplace question?  Might be more appropriate to post to the [law exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com), but I would look at their rules first.

Comment: In the future, make sure that whatever company you work for will provide you with the necessary equipment and software to do your work.

Comment: As a complete aside:  This should serve as a warning that using any personal software on company PC's should only be done on virtual machines running from a USB flashdrive that you take with you.

Comment: Is “boss” your manager with someone above him? In that case go above him.

Comment: It depends if she's working as freelance or not. But I do agree with sf02

Comment: You need to ask if suing will cost you more than it is worth. It might be something to let slide.

Comment: Tell QB what happened and have them invalidate the license key and get you a new one.

Comment: Thorbjorn - that is exactly what i did, and spent 4 hrs with them cancelling my old subscription and buying a 500.00 new one. So once he closes that qb he will not be able to open it again and he will have to go buy his own.

Answer (score 6):

If this is a licensed application, I would imagine the software owners (Intuit in this case) would have remote control over the licenses, in the event the license is being used improperly and it would need to be invalidated.  This would likely fall under such a circumstance.  You can try contacting Intuit and seeing if they can invalidate the license so you can reuse it.

Caveat: Everything Fedeco said in their answer is also correct: If the company paid for this license (or you paid for it and they reimbursed you for it) then the license is (likely) legally theirs and not yours.  If you interrupted their business continuity by trying to steal their license in this way they might have legal grounds against you.  Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks I bought the license

Answer (score 1):

It Depends from who bought the license.
If your boss gave you the permission to buy it and reimbursed you for installing on his pc or servers, he could use it.

But if the license has your name and you have paid with your money, is it yours.
Not knowing how the deal are between you and your ex boss, it isn't easy.

Surely, if you're 100% sure that the license is yours, you probably could, but speak with an attorney or someone expert in law from your local city.

Comment: Fedeco - The License is mine, he was supposed to buy his own, but the didn't want to spend the money right then, heck I couldnt even get office supplies, so i installed my software with his permission of course. I am going to the lawyers tomorrow, bc he is also harassing me and defamation of my character and a restraining order against bc he will not stop texting or emailing me.

Comment: Way to go ! became rich for the sake of others :)

Answer (score 1):

If it is a license that you purchased with your own funds, here's what you do.

## Option 1

Tell the former boss that you want to see a video in which he demonstrates uninstalling the software.  Inform him that as an alternative, you intent to visit nopiracy.com, or call 1-888-NO-PIRACY, and report him for using unlicensed software.

## Option 2

You could sue to stop him via an injunction, but your location (like mine, California) might prohibit injunctive relief in small claims and a limited/unlimited civil court would likely cost you more than buying a new license.

## Option 3

Try working out something with Intuit.  If it's not the kind of software that checks for valid license when the application starts, Intuit won't be much help because it's not in their interest to give you a new license key if they can't disable the old one.

**The short and sweet approach for this kind of stuff is don't install software you pay for on other peoples' machines!**

If you didn't pay for the license, or bought it and were later reimbursed for it, you probably have no rights to it.

(I am not an attorney.)

Comment: OPtion 2 it cost me 500 to buy a new license, but we changed the license number and the old is now invalid. Mccall

Comment: Option 1 - I like that, because he is still using my software, i can tell bc intuit has a history of live logins. THanks